React three fiber - shadow is not visible only for FBX model?
I'm working in r3f and trying to make an FBX model cast shadows on a plane mesh. Having ensured that the FBX mesh castShadow={true} and the plane receiveShadow={true}, by setting the following directionalLight settings I was able to get other meshes to display shadows, but not the FBX:
Camera / canvas settings:
<Canvas
          ref={canvasRef}
          id={"main-canvas"}
          className={shouldRender ? "main-canvas-rendering" : "main-canvas"}
          shadows={true}
          camera={{
            position: [2, 2, -2],
            fov: 75,
            near: 0.1,
            far: 150,
          }}
          gl={{
            powerPreference: "high-performance",
            alpha: false,
            antialias: false,
            stencil: false,
            preserveDrawingBuffer: true
          }}

Light settings:
<directionalLight
        position={[0, 10, -15]}
        castShadow={true}
        shadow-bias={-0.0001}
        intensity={1.5}
        shadow-mapSize-width={1024}
        shadow-mapSize-height={1024}
        shadow-camera-near={0.1}
        shadow-camera-far={20}
        shadow-camera-left={-10}
        shadow-camera-right={10}
        shadow-camera-top={10}
        shadow-camera-bottom={-10}
      />


My FBX model (minified):
const fbx = useFBX(props.data.url);
const fbx_cloned=useRef(fbx.clone());

<e.group
            objRef={theatreObj}
            theatreKey={data.name}
            additionalProps={add_props}
            name={data.uuid}
            {...rest}
            ref={groupRef}
            >
            <primitive 
                object={fbx_cloned.current} 
                scale={scale}
                position={[0,0,0]}
                ref={rootMeshObj}
                castShadow={true}
            />
</e.group>

What am I missing here to make the FBX model cast a shadow?

Any chance for Sandbox with model?
